# How to get my jQuery before() call to work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have tried using JavaScript and jQuery with my HTML file, but it is not working properly. Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style type="text/css">
      body {white-space: nowrap;}
      h1 {white-space: nowrap;}
    </style>
    <script src="jquery.js"type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title>SolicitueCotizaciones</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      function myFunction() {
      $("input[type='button'][value='Agregar Pieza']").before("<p>new text</p>")};
    </script>


    <br/> Descripcion:
    &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
    &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
    &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
    <br/>

    <textarea id="improve" rows="3" cols="20"></textarea>

    </p>
    <div class="divider"/>
    <div style="align-items:left"></div>
    <p>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="button" value="+Agregar Pieza" onclick="myFunction()">
    </p>


  </body>
</html>
```

I have also tried copying code from tutorial websites that work properly but when I run them in my computer, they stop working. Can anyone help me figure out what's happening and what I should do to solve it?

EDIT: What I'm trying to achieve is to add the new text above the "+agregar pieza" button and below the text input box labeled "descripcion" once you press the "+agregar pieza" button, but this never happens. I have tried the corrections that were posted in the comments, and I edited the code above to include them. However, as of this edit, it is still not working at all. I would like to use the .before command from jquery to achieve the desired result, but if there is a better way to do this, I would like to know.

Comment: please say what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: where do you call the jquery library? it should be in your head tag

Comment: Move the script to the bottom

Comment: [**Please read the jQuery tutorial!**](http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/) I can't stress this enough. The tutorial exists exactly for that reason: To show you help you get started with jQuery. You don't have to *try* and wonder about anything, you just have to follow the instructions.

Comment: When debugging JavaScript, open up your browser console, and keep an eye out for errors. This one would definitely have shown up.

Comment: After formatting your code I see that you have two closing </span> tags and no opening tag (was the first one supposed to be an opening tag?), and you have a closing </form> tag but no opening tag.

Comment: The tags are ramaning from the previous full code that i took off from the original post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, jQuery is not native to your browser, you need to load it before using it. The tutorials should help you here.

Second, your code is not correct, it should be something closer to this:

```
$("input[type='button'][value='Agregar Pieza']").before("<p>new text</p>");
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wKhap/

Answer (score 1):

It isn't working because you need to import jQuery before using it. In order to do so, you need to add this tag:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Add this **before** any other references to scripts that use jQuery.

Comment: Note that one of the main recommendations on the jQuery site is NOT to load jquery-latest on your page http://blog.jquery.com/2014/07/03/dont-use-jquery-latest-js/

Comment: If you're after a CDN for jQuery, I believe Google and Microsoft offer free ones.